# Критерии оценки ответов

Tags: обсуждение

Наверняка поднимался вопрос, но я не нашел.

Был задан вопрос
[Защищённая и закрытая область видимости свойств и методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559019/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2/559205?noredirect=1#comment725795_559205)

На него, соответственно, был дан ответ (не мной). Ответ короткий, не развернутый, но, по сути, верный.(пока писал, успели удалить, посему приведу по памяти)

> сделайте для каждого свойства геттеры

Кто-то пометил его как требующий удаления с признаком `"не является ответом на вопрос"`

Насколько я понимаю, так как ответ описывает совершенно корректное и правильное решение заданного вопроса, удалять его не следовало.

Так ли это?

Comment: Скорее всего, [не следовало](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3568/181100). Вероятно, в этой ситуации расчёт на то, что прилетят минусы и автор сам захочет съесть собственный ответ без соли :Р

Comment: @D-side да, я читал этот топик, но он несколько про другое имхо. Там заведомо неправильные ответы обсуждаются, а тут правильный, но "не по феншую"

Comment: Да не, там точно такая же ситуация. Ответ, правда, менее содержательный чем здесь, но решение (сработавшее) он содержит. Система тревог "не ответ" не предназначена для удаления таких.